# Update file in HDFS through Hue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hue

I know that HDFS is about write once and read multiple times type. As per my knowledge it's not possible to update a file (randomly) in HDFS because a file is stored in a distributed environment (as blocks) with each block replicated on other nodes which would be difficult for data-node to update even these replicated blocks.

But, my question is it possible to update files in HDFS using *hue* tool?. Because, I've updated many files (stored in HDFS) using the *hue* tool and ran map-reduce jobs on it. So, how is it possible for *hue* to update the files in HDFS. Does *hue* do something in background? Are the updates made through *hue* really updated to same file? or *hue* deletes the file and re-writes the whole file (including our new data we want to update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hue deletes and re-writes the whole file as HDFS does not support editions. You can notice that Hue limits the edition to only small files for now.

Here is a blog post to learn more about the [HDFS Filebrowser](http://gethue.com/file-browser-enhancements-hdfs-operations-made-easy/).

Comment: oh okay, that was my assumption too. Thanks for the reply and posting the link.